# Is there any way to avoid the error ClassNotFoundException (Spring Initializr)?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, classnotfoundexception

when I generate Gradle-Kotlin-Spring Boot project and start it in Intellij Idea,
I receive an error message:

Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.%someClassNameKt%
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  com.example.%someClassNameKt%

No additional setting were made.

I tried to point out main class placing in the build script:

```
application {
    mainClassName = "com.example.%someClassNameKt%"
}
```

But it's to no avail.

Is it a known bug or how to avoid this error?

I really checked lots of similar questions but it didn't help

Comment: How did you generate this Gradle-Kotlin-Spring project? ``%someClassNameKt%`` looks to me like a variable which should have been replaced by some user given name during the project generation part. I suggest to look into the steps of generating such project. If the problem is consistently reproducible update your question with them. Also does this error only happen when you try to run this project in IntelliJ (possibly not)? If not then it's unrelated to IntellJ (again update your question here). Hope these pointers help.

Answer (score 1):

You should not need the '%' in your mainClassName, and that may be causing the error.

Do you have a class named `someClassNameKt` in the package `com.example`?
It's unusual for classes to be camel-case, are you sure this is correct?

Open up your main application class, and at the very top check what package it is in. For example:
`package com.example`

Assuming your class name is, say, 'SomeApplication' `SomeApplication.java`, and is in the package `com.example`, this would work:

```
application {
    mainClassName = "com.example.SomeApplication"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple - avoid cyrillic symbols in directories names on your project path